# post form data and show in server

Tags: html, forms, node.js

I have a simple form, I just want to see which fields are sent to server. But in the server side, I only get the `<input type="text">` field value. Why the server can't get the `<select>` and `<input type="file" />` value?

HTML:

```
<form action="http://localhost:8100/" method="POST">
        <div>
            <select>
                <option value="op1" selected="selected">Option1</option>
                <option value="op2">Option2</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div>
            <input type="file" value="select a file"/>
        </div>

        <div>
            <label>Your Hero: </label><input type="text" name="hero" />
        </div>

        <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>
```

Server:

```
var http = require("http");

http.createServer(function(req, res) {
        if (req.method == 'POST') {
            var body = '';
            req.on('data', function (data) {
                body += data;
                console.log(body);
            });
            req.on('end', function () {
                console.log("request data complete");
            });
            res.end("post request");
        } else {
            res.end("get request");
        }

    }).listen(8100);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `select` and `file input` elements are missing `name` attribute. All form elements you wish to be submitted must have a unique `name` attribute. `name` attribute will the identifier for the value of element when the data has been submitted through POST and GET.

You can read about it in the specs in here: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#naming-form-controls:-the-name-attribute

Answer (score 1):

I think you just forgot the "name" attributes in this form elments. Add it and it should work. Cheers